# Jaspersoft Studio JDBC to Sql Server not liking dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, jasper-reports

I have tried server variances of the following script in an attempt to pull date from sql-server into a jasper report studio project with no luck. The following produced no errors but a warning that "Date is not recognized as a built in function name. Do you want to proceed anyways?" I Believe the problem is tied to how jdbc deal with Dates vs Sql Server's way of working with them but I am unsure how to move forward. What can I do to fix this.

```
    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT '' AS id3, ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(amount), 0), 0) AS amount_3, DATE('now','-3 month')  AS Date_3 FROM Sales WHERE date('YEAR', purchase_date) =  date('YEAR', Date_3)  AND DATE('MONTH', purchase_date) = date('MONTH', Date_3)) C
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT '' AS id2, ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(amount), 0), 0) AS amount_2, DATE('now','-2 month')  AS Date_2 FROM Sales WHERE date('YEAR', purchase_date) =  date('YEAR', Date_2)  AND DATE('MONTH', purchase_date) = date('MONTH', Date_2)) B
     ON id3 = id2 LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT '' AS id1, ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(amount), 0), 0) AS amount_1, DATE('now','-1 month')  AS Date_1 FROM Sales WHERE date('YEAR', purchase_date) =  date('YEAR', Date_1)  AND DATE('MONTH', purchase_date) = date('MONTH', Date_1)) A
     ON id2 = id1

My previous attempt, which worked well in SSMS, looked something like the following:

 SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT '' AS id3, ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(amount),0),0) FORMAT(purchase_date, 'MMM yy') AS Date_db_3, DATEADD(month, -3, getdate()) AS Date_3 FROM SALES  GROUP BY purchase_date HAVING YEAR(purchase_date) = YEAR(DATEADD(month, 3, getdate())) AND MONTH(purchase_date) = MONTH(DATEADD(month, -3, getdate())) C
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT '' AS id2, ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(amount),0),0) FORMAT(purchase_date, 'MMM yy') AS Date_db_2, DATEADD(month, -2, getdate()) AS Date_2 FROM SALES  GROUP BY purchase_date HAVING YEAR(purchase_date) = YEAR(DATEADD(month, -2, getdate())) AND MONTH(purchase_date) = MONTH(DATEADD(month, -2, getdate())) B
ON id3 = id2 LEFT JOIN
(SELECT '' AS id1, ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(amount),0),0) FORMAT(purchase_date, 'MMM yy') AS Date_db_1, DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()) AS Date_1 FROM SALES  GROUP BY purchase_date HAVING YEAR(purchase_date) = YEAR(DATEADD(month, -1, getdate())) AND MONTH(purchase_date) = MONTH(DATEADD(month, -1, getdate())) A
 ON id2 = id1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up that JDBC was lying when it said the code had errors. the following code did work.

```
 SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT '' AS id3, ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(amount),0),0) FORMAT(purchase_date, 'MMM yy') AS Date_db_3, DATEADD(month, -3, getdate()) AS Date_3 FROM SALES  WHERE YEAR(purchase_date) = YEAR(DATEADD(month, 3, getdate())) AND MONTH(purchase_date) = MONTH(DATEADD(month, -3, getdate())) C
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT '' AS id2, ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(amount),0),0) FORMAT(purchase_date, 'MMM yy') AS Date_db_2, DATEADD(month, -2, getdate()) AS Date_2 FROM SALES  WHERE YEAR(purchase_date) = YEAR(DATEADD(month, -2, getdate())) AND MONTH(purchase_date) = MONTH(DATEADD(month, -2, getdate())) B
ON id3 = id2 LEFT JOIN
(SELECT '' AS id1, ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(amount),0),0) FORMAT(purchase_date, 'MMM yy') AS Date_db_1, DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()) AS Date_1 FROM SALES  WHERE YEAR(purchase_date) = YEAR(DATEADD(month, -1, getdate())) AND MONTH(purchase_date) = MONTH(DATEADD(month, -1, getdate())) A
 ON id2 = id1
```